# Replace symbol particular position in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Every 3 | position Need to add symbol below like output.

Samples:

```
input :'12Hr|AP,1.8|KR,10.8|KE,10.8|TN,2.9|'

**output :'12Hr|AP,1.8|KR,10.8|@KE,10.8|TN,2.9|'**

input : '12Hr|AP,1.8|KR,10.8|KE,10.8|TN,2.9|UP,3.40|KR,4.9|'

**output : '12Hr|AP,1.8|KR,10.8|@KE,10.8|TN,2.9|UP,3.40|@KR,4.9|SS,4.9|AP,7.3|@'**
```

Comment: Not the fastest solution if this is a repeat process, or one that is time intensive (depending on the dataset size). But if it HAS to be done in SQL, you can enable regex, and use a query that matches every `nth` occurrence. Link on how to enable regex:
https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-regex-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: Best would be to not do it in SQL.

Comment: @juergend+1 agreed, this seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: According to your sample output, you aren't *replacing* the pipe (`|`) with an at symbol (`@`), you're adding one after it. Otherwise I would expect `'12Hr|AP,1.8|KR,10.8@KE,10.8|TN,2.9|'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. The term "replace" is used incorrectly, as you don't replace the pipe (`|`) in your expected output
2. The 2nd output is wrong, as the input value terminates at `KR,4.9`, but you have 2 additional values after it.

As has been mentioned, this shouldn't be done in T-SQL, but that doesn't mean it can't be. One method would be to use a string splitter, split it on the pipes, and then reaggregate it, adding the `@` character in the right indexed items.

You can't, however, use SQL Server's in built `STRING_SPLIT` for this, as it doesn't respect ordinal positions. I therefore use [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2); this does mean I *assume* your value can't be longer than 8000 bytes in size.

I then use SQL Server's in built `STRING_AGG` function (if you don't have 2017+ you'll need to use the old `FOR XML PATH` method) to reaggregate. Inside the aggregate, I add a `@` at the start of the string where the `(itemnumber-1) % 3` evaluates to `0` (every 3rd item, off set by one) and excludes the 1st item (as this would evaluate to `0`).

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN (DS.ItemNumber-1) % 3 = 0 AND DS.ItemNumber != 1 THEN '@' ELSE '' END + DS.Item,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber)
FROM (VALUES(1,'12Hr|AP,1.8|KR,10.8|KE,10.8|TN,2.9|'),
            (2,'12Hr|AP,1.8|KR,10.8|KE,10.8|TN,2.9|UP,3.40|KR,4.9|'))V(SomeID,YourString)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.YourString,'|') DS
GROUP BY V.SomeID;
```